# React js - detect backbutton

Tags: reactjs

in reactjs don't work onbeforeunload, this code:

```
ComponentDidMount
     window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.';
       };
```

work with only update(F5, Ctrl + R, update) but don't work when click back button or backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onbeforeunload` will only be triggered if pressing the back button causes the browser to leave the page. If you are using hashes to track in-page state, then it's not going to do anything for you.

If that is the case, you should use `window.onhashchange` instead. If that's not the case, please provide more detail in your question.

Comment: my clients may change page but his doesn't change with back, onhashchange is working every change url address.

Comment: yes, it's working, but i want that client doesn't click back button, now he show alert when client already left previous page, I writed, windows.onhashchange = function(){ alert(Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.')